# what code is this?

Tags: html

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0in;"><meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title><meta name="GENERATOR" content="OpenOffice.org 2.4  (Win32)"><style type="text/css">   <!--        @page { size: 8.5in 11in; margin: 0.79in }      P { margin-bottom: 0.08in } --> </style> </meta></meta></p>
```

While copying text from some sites, this code got appended automatically. Can you please help me with what code is this??? will this affect the appearance of other text on the site?? why does this text gets appended???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases and depending on the program and operative system, whenever you copy a line of text from your browser, you also get some some format along it.

If you are using OpenOffice try pasting with the option "without format"

Answer (score 1):

If you are pasting into word you can use the method described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA010429611033.aspx).  Being slightly lazy I will sometimes paste it into notepad and then copy/paste it into what ever other document i need (which is ironically more work...)  This also seems to remove formatting.

Comment: Not only formatting, but Notepad and other text editors will replace "smart quotes" with "dumb quotes", etc.  This will help avoid those awkward unreadable characters that paste-w/o-formatting doesn't always remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all this:

```
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title><meta name="GENERATOR" content="OpenOffice.org 2.4  (Win32)"><style type="text/css">   <!--        @page { size: 8.5in 11in; margin: 0.79in }      P { margin-bottom: 0.08in } --> </style> </meta></meta>
```

That html got appended because your editor thought it was html that belonged in the body tag.